# Website cache folder, best location? Inside or outside webroot?

Tags: php, security, caching, server

I am curious if there is a best practice concerning the location of a website's cache folder (templates, images, etc)?

I often see it residing in the webroot with `index.html`/`index.php` like so,

```
Server
`-- /var/
    `-- www/
        -- example.com/
            |-- .git/
            |-- public_html/
            |   |-- cache/
            |   |-- assets/
            |   `-- index.html
            |-- src/
            |-- test/
            |-- .gitignore
            `-- package.json
```

However, would it be considered bad practice or create any security concerns if I place the cache folder up one level with the rest of the private project files (.git, node_modules, etc)? Like so...

```
Server
`-- /var/
    `-- www/
        -- example.com/
            |-- .git/
            |-- cache/
            |-- public_html/
            |   |-- assets/
            |   `-- index.html
            |-- src/
            |-- test/
            |-- .gitignore
            `-- package.json
```

Apologies if this isn't a question for here, but I wasn't able to find much information on best practices regarding project folder structure for the cache. The only stuff I could find was about best practices on using the browser cache and other caching tools.

Thanks!

Comment: If the cache is going to be just static html files I would just put it inside the docroot so it doesn't need a custom serving mechanism.

Comment: If it's cached content that's going to be served to a client (compiled templates, resized images, etc), then put it under the docroot. If not, don't, as you're potentially introducing security issues by having sensitive data accessible to the public.

Comment: @iainn That's what I thought, but I wasn't quite sure. Thanks a lot! :)